# Minimal svelte + vitejs configuration for pre-rendered single-page app?

Tags: svelte, vite, prerender, static-site-generation

I have a very basic setup for Svelte with ViteJS for a single-page app that requires no routing and has all dependencies inlined by the `vite-plugin-singlefile` plugin.

The one thing that I cannot get to work is pre-rendered markup.

I would like to have the single-page app pre-rendered at build time, with the initial markup inlined in `index.html` for SEO, and hydration on the client side.

The `vite-ssr-plugin` seems to be targeting this scenario but incompatible with `vite-plugin-singlefile`. It generates a whole bunch of client / server files when used alone.

`sveltekit` on the other hand seems to be targeting more advanced scenarios and also generates a myriad of output files.

Is there any simpler solution?